# Video player integration in answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Many posts here involve explaining the procedure/process involved to achieve the desired results, whose demonstration videos / concept-explaining videos(with animations) usually can be found on sites like YouTube / Vimeo etc.,

How about we have video embed capability while writing answers? 
Sure, we can link to the youtube video, but nothing like having an embedded video in your answers.

Let me know what you guys think.

Comment: FYI, it's a feature in some SE sites already, like sci-fi. I'm meh about this, but I think we need proof first. Proof that there is a considerable number of answers where videos are being linked to, and sadly, that's not the case, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Can you give some examples of good answers that require the user to watch a video? Imo if you explain something completely, you shouldn't *need* to link to another explanation video. I don't think I've ever needed videos. It's not that this is a *bad* suggestion - it's just a question of how useful it is i.e. whether it is worth spending time on implementing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am against it.

While the implementation is already present as it is used on other sites, it will add considerable load time to the page itself. We are already loading one of the heaviest extensions possible, i.e. MathJax. For especially heavy MathJax sites loading already takes a very long time. Adding to that an implementation that further increases this time is not desirable. The sites that have it enabled don't use MathJax so that is less of a problem there. Apart from that, for example in movies.se you need the player because you are referring to a certain clip.

On chemistry.se the answer should be self-contained. That does in principle mean that anything important in the video should be written down as the answer. If the answer consists only of a youtube video, then (almost) always it will be deleted as a link only answer.

For me personally I do not see the necessity or the benefit. If you would like to include an animation of sorts, you can use animated gifs.